# Ajax with PHP - Is Ajax a replacement of server side "View" of MVC?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using PHP mvc framework (Codeigniter) for my web blog.

I am going to implement Ajax for the first time to see the real benefit myself.

I guess what I've done from the view such as formatting and display result on html page can now be replaced by the Ajax implementation. So I guess the view of the the server side mvc would no longer be used.

With a form validation, it is suggested to gear up with logic for both client and server in case javascript gets bypassed. I guess the same concept applies here with Ajax when javascript is disabled from client browser. I mean, you get no data when it's disabled. What would be the back up solution for this scenario like how validation is handled?

Comment: How is AJAX a replacement for views? How are you gonna display Ajax calls witouth "views"? AJAX is used to make background requests to the server. Also, you don't validate server side "just in case", you do that because it's the right thing to do; js validation is a kindness to users in great part. The backup option when js is disabled is submit forms they way they always did

Comment: You should ALWAYS validate server-side regardless of how much client-side validation you do.

Comment: Make your validations server-side. If you're using ajax on post requests, you can easily output response in an appropriate alert div.

Comment: @DamienPirsy Well, you display it with javascript dom manipulation which is another way of implementing "view". I am just saying it because client side javascript can have separate mvc pattern other than server side pattern.

Comment: I am a bit confused with mvc pattern that can be implemented from both client and server side. Would it make more sense to say your application is built with mvc pattern and the view of this can have another level of mvc like backbone.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've asked two questions but I'm just going to answer the first one: can AJAX replace the role a server-side view traditionally had?

In MVC web frameworks the view is a template for converting data passed in from the controller into HTML, however, client-side templating languages have become quite popular and are a perfectly reasonable alternative to rendering HTML output on the server, and they have definite advantages.

Firstly, since you're not sending an entire HTML payload to the client browser but instead just the content, you can save significantly on bandwidth. Generating the HTML client side allows you to transmit only data (like JSON or XML) to the client. The server side view would simply contain script tags pointing to the JavaScript templates and the content payload.

Secondly, since these JavaScript templates can be served up from a CDN, you benefit from the speed of those networks plus caching across pages, so the user is likely only downloading those templates which are unique to a specific page as well as data.

However, there are some disadvantages, such as SEO, although there are some workarounds for that. One option would be to serve up an SEO friendly version of the page to crawlers using a server side view, or simply render your templates server-side using Node.js or Rhino. The beauty of writing templates in a language that compiled to JavaScript is that both the server and the browser and execute them, which can be said for no other language.

Comment: cleint side templating has its own downfalls to be honest. issue is, client side templating __can not replace__ server side views. ofcourse you can send a json format for less bandwith but filtering it to suit your need may become tiresome and in some cases not feasible. It is suppose to __enhance__ and not __replace__.

Comment: Why can't client side templates fill the role of server-side views? Why must they only enhance rather than replace? On a technical level you can't get rid of server-side views because you have to deliver the HTML to wire up the templates and request the data payload, but at that point most of your view logic is on the client.